# How to hide status bar on a view

Tags: ios, statusbar, ios13, xcode11

Before someone marks it duplicate, I want to say that I've seen all those answers and none helps me. Also they are donkey years old solution which don't work anymore.

I want to hide status bar only on a view.

```
Info.plist settings:
Status bar style: Light Content
View controller-based status bar appearance: NO
```

With above settings I've tried many solutions but none worked. The only way I could get it to work is following

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Hide status bar - this is the only working solution for me
    // Setter for 'isStatusBarHidden' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}
```

However this working solution gives warning in Xcode

```
// Setter for 'isStatusBarHidden' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]
```

The solution for above warning is to use those workarounds which again don't work.

Is there any simple and definite way to hide status bar on a view?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to set the `prefersStatusBarHidden` property on the view controller that needs a hidden status bar. Add the following property in your view controller:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { true }
```

Tried this in a couple of simple apps and works like a charm for me.

Comment: It works only if View controller-based status bar appearance is set to YES in info.plist. In my case this value is NO so it doesn't work. I've already tried it and tested.